# How to retrieve bearer token from header (rest sdk)

Tags: c++, rest, cpprest-sdk

I have worked a few times with a REST SDK. I want to retrieve a `Bearer` token from the response headers, using C++.

Image from Postman:
[image]

I have tried this:

```
CMyClass::SomeMethod(const web::http::http_request& Request)
{
    const web::http::http_headers& headers = Request.headers();
    web::http::http_headers::const_iterator it = headers.find(web::http::header_names::authorization);
    if (it != headers.end())
    {
        std::cout << "+++\t" << it->first.c_str() << "\t" << it->second.c_str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

but I only get this:

[image]

Which tells me that I have done something wrong.

So, how can I retrieve the `Bearer` token from `web::http::http_request` header?

Comment: Does behavior improve if you dont c_str() ?

Comment: Of course that I have tried without c_str(), same behavior ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you are seeing means that you are not passing `char*` string pointers to `std::cout`.

Assuming you are using [Microsoft's REST SDK](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/) (you did not say), its [`web::http::http_headers`](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1http__headers.html) class holds `utility::string_t` values, and `utility::string_t` is defined as `std::wstring` on Windows (despite what the [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/namespaceutility.html) says), not `std::string` like you are expecting.

Which means you are passing `wchar_t*` string pointers to `std:::cout`, which does not have an `operator<<` for `wchar_t*`, but does have one for `void*`, hence the output you see.

You would need to use `std::wcout` instead, or else convert the `std::wstring` data to `std::string` before printing it.